# Redux, como acessar variaveis do state da store em funções

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Olá, minha dúvida é se consigo acessar as variáveis da store em funções, algo como:

```js
--usuarioReducer.js--

const initialState = {
   usuario: {},
   isAuth: false
}

--root.js--
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class App extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      if(!**variavel_is_auth_store**) { // Se isAuth === false, redireciona para Login
         return <Redirect to={'/Login'} />
      }
   }
}
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu pegar aquela variável do Reducer que fica na Store e utilizá-la em funções

Comment: tem sim, é para isso que é objetivo.

Comment: Tá, mas como fazer?

Comment: o seu código minimo precisa atualizar todo o código relacionado com redux ... só isso fica dificil responder

Comment: um link bom de estudo: https://medium.com/reactbrasil/iniciando-com-redux-c14ca7b7dcf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como foi dito a ideia do react-redux é esta mesma. Para ter acesso a store em seus componentes você precisa se conectar a store e fazer o mapeamente do state da store que precisa. Isto é feito com o connect do redux que é um HOC que necessita de uma função com a configuração de mapeamente que precisa. Geralmente este mapeamente por padronização a gente chama a função de mapStateToProps. A documentação explica bem isto. Mas se procurar na internet como fazer o mapStateToProps tem muito conteudo.
Este link detalha bem, veja: [Mapeando o state da store](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/demystifying-mapstatetoprops-for-beginners-to-react-and-redux-27136721a3c6)